# How to convert an array of strings into a number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching data from an API which returns currency exchange rates like so:

```
{"EUR_USD":1.044136}
```

I was able to manipulate the fetched data using:

`const rate = Object.values(data).splice(11,5);`

which returns `1.044`

However, my next problem comes when trying to parseFloat this object into a number.. for some reason it only returns the first digit so in case of "1.044" it'd convert it into "1".

How can I handle this ? I'm thinking to perhaps map thru the rate array and then parseFloat everything..?

`const parsedRate = rate.map(i => i).parseFloat();`
would this even work ?

ok guys - sorry for taking your time and I appreciate all your answers! but I had JSON.stringify on the string and that's what was causing the problem... SORRY!!!

Comment: If that's how you're getting the data, why not just use `data.EUR_USD` rather than a strange splice call? Then it would already be a Number value...

Comment: well, there are multiple choices of currencies to convert.. should I just try to get each currency symbol and plug it into ```data.EUR_USD``` like so:  ``` `data.${currOne}_${currTwo}` ``` i think this might be the best solution tbh, but I still need to find a way to parseFloat everything

Comment: Perhaps you could be more forthcoming with the actual form the data are coming in, and how you need to access the data. As mentioned, the data within the EUR_USD property is already a "float", so there's no need to parse it as one.

Comment: I want to do a currency rate exchange, for example let's say the rate is 1.044 ( as stated in the example ) - and someone wants to see how much 100 euro would be in USD - then it should convert it into 104.4

Comment: Okay... That doesn't answer the request made, which is to tell us exactly what data you are getting back and how you are accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example data you have supplied is an plain old Javascript object literal:

```
{"EUR_USD":1.044136}
```

You just need to access the exchange rate(s) by their name. Assuming it's in a variable called `rates`, it's just

```
const rate = rates.EUR_USD;
```

to assign the numeric value `1.044136` to the variable `rate`.

If, however, you have a ***string*** containing the JSON response from the API:

```
"{\"EUR_USD\":1.044136}"
```

And you're trying to use `string.splice()` to extract bits from it, you are going about it the wrong way.

All you have to do to rehydrate that JSON response body into an object is to use `JSON.parse()`:

```
const json = callUpstreamExchangeRateApi();
const rates = JSON.parse(json);
const rate  = rates.EUR_USD;
```

Answer (score 1):

array.map(Number) would return an array of whatever is being mapped converted to number (assuming its possible)

Comment: 1, NaN, 0, 4, 4 it's giving me this as of now.. I could potentially turn NaN into "." - however I'm still not sure if I'd be able to parseFloat it afterwards

Comment: Not sure what you are exactly trying to do, but if this is the approach you are sticking with, assuming you have an array of [1, '.', 0, 4, 4] you can then:
Number([1, '.', 0, 4, 4].join(''))
and you will get 1.044

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with different length of keys.
You have to use Object.values

```js
const data = [{"EUR_NOUSD":"1.044136"}, {"EUR_EURO":"1.15"},{"EUR_CANDIES":"2.333"}]

const getValue = currency => Number(Object.values(currency))

console.log(data.map(getValue))
```